# Incomprehension in the sum of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`T1` and `P1` are two numpy arrays respectively encompassing temperatures (in Kelvin, between 100 and 250) and pressures (in Pascals, between 700 and 1). They have exactly the same shape `432*45*135*135` Each element of those arrays are `numpy.float32`. Here is my code :

```
1  T2=T1+1.
2  P2=P1+1.

3  print np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(T2,T1)))
4  print np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(P2,P1)))

5  print ((T2-T1)-1.<1e-3).sum()
6  print ((P2-P1)-1.<1e-3).sum()
```

And here are my outputs :

```
1.6792e+07
2.24963e+07

354294000
354294000
```

I can't understand why :

- Instructions 3 and 4 do not give the same results, because `T2-T1` and `P2-P1` should both be equal to a `432*45*135*135` array full of 1s.
- None of instruction 3 and 4 give the good results, which is given by instruction 5 and 6, and equals to the number of elements in the array (`432*45*135*135=354294000`)
- Some elements in `T2-T1` and `P2-P1` are not equal to 1., which can be seen if I increase the precision of the comparison in instructions 5 and 6.

Expressions

```
print ((T2-T1)-1.<1e-5).sum()
print ((P2-P1)-1.<1e-5).sum()
```

Give the output :

```
354293978
354041812
```

I can imagine that those problems have something to do with precision, but I should not encounter this problem using dtype `numpy.float32`. I tried :

```
T2=T1+np.float32(1.)
P2=P1+np.float32(1.)
```

Which does not change anything. Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the sum of a large amount of numbers is a tricky problem, since computers may not represent numbers with enough precision to do that.

32-bit floating point has only around 7 digits of precision. As a consequence, if you add a small number to a large number, and the ratio between them is more than `2^24` (≈ `1.7*10^7`) then the result may be exactly that large number. So when doing the sum, once your sum reaches that value, adding +1 will not change the sum anymore.

You may *just* get away with using double precision (but the result can still have quite a large error with that amount of values). Otherwise you'll have to use an algorithm like Kahan summation, or, if there are no negative numbers, do the sum in stages. For instance you can calculate the sums of the 432 numbers every a row first, then calculate the sums of 45 rows in a column, etc.

Comment: Thanks roeland. I understand your point, but am I not suppose in that case to find the same value (1.7*10^7) in every cases, corresponding to the limit ?

Comment: @ArnaudPROST Not sure, I think it depends on the exact values in the array (they are not exactly 1.0), and how those intermediate results are rounded. You can do a test with summing an array with all elements initialized to exactly 1.0.

Comment: If I create an array `test=np.zeros([432,45,135,135])` then do `test=test+1.0` and `print test.sum()` I obtain `1.67772e+07` that I interpret as the limit you were talking about, over which adding 1 does not change anything anymore. But I still don't understand how we can go over it with the pressure array, reaching `2.24963e+07`

Comment: Probably the latter array has elements which are a bit larger than 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Following @roeland lines, this code does the trick :

```
T1=T1.astype(np.float64)
T2=T1+np.float64(1.)
P1=P1.astype(np.float64)
P2=P1+np.float64(1.)

print np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(T2,T1))))
print np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(P2,P1))))
```

Gives the correct output :

```
354294000.0
354294000.0
```